# Cannot import name 'GraphQL' from 'strawberry.fastapi'

Tags: python, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I am trying to run an strawberry example from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fastapi/fastapi_using_graphql.htm) but it does not work.

I have the code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import strawberry
from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQL


@strawberry.type
class Book:
   title: str
   author: str
   price: int

@strawberry.type
class Query:
   @strawberry.field
   def book(self) -> Book:
      return Book(title="Computer Fundamentals", author="Sinha", price=300)

schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)

graphql_app = GraphQL(schema)
app = FastAPI()

app.add_route("/book", graphql_app)
app.add_websocket_route("/book", graphql_app)
```

but when I try to run it with `uvicorn Mystrawberry:app --reload`
it says

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GraphQL' from 'strawberry.fastapi'
```

Now, in the Strawberry documentation examples they use GraphQLRouter rather than GraphQL, and I don't know if that is an old version or a typo.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem your tutorial is incorrect or out of date. Take a look at the [official documentation](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/integrations/fastapi), it seems like the way to do it is to do `from strawberry.fastapi import GraphQLRouter`, and include that router in your FastAPI application.